# How to specify a date in the Log4Net directory?

Tags: asp.net, .net, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I want to write logs to current date directory for ASP.NET site by using `Log4Net` lib.

Like this:
`<file value=".\Content\logs\{$currentDate}\TestLog.log" />`

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `log4net.Util.PatternString` to do this, in your case do the following:

Remove this:

```
<file value="TestLog.log" />
```

And add this:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value=".\Content\logs\%date{yyyyMMdd}\\TestLog.log" />
```

For further info please refer to the documentation:

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.PatternString.html

Comment: It's not work. I got `Content\logs\%date` directory instead of `Content\logs\23 Nov 2013 ...`. Other patterns like %date{yyyy MMM dd} also not work.

Comment: what version are you using? the latest?

Comment: Latest from NuGet: 1.2.12.0.

Comment: Will try it, give me a few mins

Comment: For now I found only way to specify date into file name:       `<file value=".\Content\Logs\" />
      <datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />`

Comment: Sorry, I've tested the above and it def works with new version. Please accept if it works for you.